# Calling webservice with parameters c#

Tags: c#, web-services, parameters

I am new to webservices. I'm trying to call one this way just to see the result:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(getServiceResult("http://prod.sivaonline.pt/SAG.WS.SIVA.SVOLB2C/ViaturasNovas.asmx?wsdl"));
}

public string getServiceResult(string serviceUrl)
{
    HttpWebRequest HttpWReq;
    HttpWebResponse HttpWResp;
    HttpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
    HttpWReq.Method = "GetMarcas";
    HttpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWReq.GetResponse();
    if (HttpWResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
    //Consume webservice with basic XML reading, assumes it returns (one) string
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(HttpWResp.GetResponseStream());
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
        return reader.Value;
        }
    }
    return String.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
    throw new Exception("Error on remote IP to Country service: " + HttpWResp.StatusCode.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now, it doesn't give me any message box. Is this normal? I want to add some parameters, like:

```
configurador=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio makes it easy to call web services by creating proxy classes for them on the client side. You create an object of the proxy class and calls its respective methods, which are internally converted into SOAP calls by the framework. Simply right-click on your project and use **Add Service Reference** instead of using `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: Ok, i did that. Now, i can i retrieve a string with the xml?

Comment: For any serializable type, you can define a method in your service and set its return type to that. For returning or sending XML, the simplest option is to set param (or return) type of your function to string. Other, more complex options are also available.

Comment: I Am not understanding. As i said, i'm new to webservices, and i can't change the webservice, i just want to access it in my application, and get some data. For example, the method GetMarcas is in the webservice and gets all the car trademarks in the server database, and that method has parameteres, like 'active=true'. How should i do to get the active trademarks?

Comment: It is simple as simple. If you have the URL of your web service, just use **Add Service Reference** (**Add Web Reference** therein) and provide it with the URL. VS will generate a proxy class that you can then create an object of. You'll see your method(s) (**GetMarcas** in this case) in the list of member functions of your proxy object. You can call this proxy method just like a normal .net function. The proxy function defintion will also take parameters from you, just like the original web service method.